# Working with XML Digital Signature in java and getting some unwanted '&#13;

Tags: java, xml, signature, digital

I am Trying to genereate my XML signature. When Running the below examlple
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-xml-digital-signature-api-overview-and-tutorial.html#GUID-1152D2A5-ECBB-4727-9B0F-1941E4171108

And getting teh below response. Inside signature 
 is getting which is expected and not shown in the example. Need assistance to resolve that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><BusinessMessage>
  <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01"/>
  <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.003.001.07" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.003.001.07 camt.003.001.07.xsd">
    <GetAcct>
      <MsgHdr>
        <MsgId>MTN000004</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2021-04-22T15:41:29+02:00</CreDtTm>
      </MsgHdr>
      <AcctQryDef>
        <AcctCrit>
          <NewCrit>
            <SchCrit>
              <AcctId>
                <EQ>
                  <Othr>
                    <Id>250788123456</Id>
                  </Othr>
                </EQ>
              </AcctId>
              <AcctOwnr>
                <CtctDtls>
                  <MobNb>250788123456</MobNb>
                </CtctDtls>
              </AcctOwnr>
            </SchCrit>
          </NewCrit>
        </AcctCrit>
      </AcctQryDef>
    </GetAcct>
  </Document>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>i41j0dS1uwC8ggex3M3YYND05g3OipfKT+kiByLo2gY=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>KBBupI04c6OyfqrJVzNtEnyYHsm8i9ZLa7gPFIuvj+gruFls0GWHikzowFTJNqPfPkML7n/sv4dF&#13;
1QyAE9RRrvdNMEVoR5WYIsg0J61QgNtx/5Lis30qVEPVo66GOpXoysu6cZ9MnnpiclXzzuk/ZIsH&#13;
2tZSvlPqN/rC/W4xOet8UO4dCvoj/tcwr6ukJOh3ArDS2q/AMdzgiyNExaDXx3vGl/wecVgAe/3U&#13;
oyG5MWTGOMMFAlk2aGq+Vm/9faePs0st7LvSXT9ySWtz3XHCl1DYmT20bBTw97tJxJeP6+g5q+iE&#13;
1FlJxc5rtsyDOxEpA3cfXXsgLNW/3I1Gpp+2dg==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>okTuIE0BJYsd2aX9mw+CyGZt/JwxoaE2RGonnz32biHT8C3rTPNOFz6JPaPxHnZVOvKGxZNAWveM&#13;
u6o+BI5NHTAon+7hOHeYp2WoBp+nDwMTjGWkb6K8NUwYw+pBNJnqqyLzUTVvuZDg2VRsflbLhITF&#13;
wAKTTnfARBskdKpmY1s6/Unm12cFBiBVHVxPvnR6mwMSZfkU9LY/1Kx11XKyXxPqzzezDwiX6aqr&#13;
Wag2ouOFyLaXBvdUxPQkTSOvOJWmdH/E5tItf7+NbTUehaHLYkfCR5YLcAstD6zUfM5YuEKK3DLo&#13;
LdhiID9EDBCs6nkpp4GgOkquvgD+l8dGKe3eFQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue></KeyInfo></Signature></BusinessMessage>
```

Expected output-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><BusinessMessage>
  <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01"/>
  <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.003.001.07" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.003.001.07 camt.003.001.07.xsd">
    <GetAcct>
      <MsgHdr>
        <MsgId>MTN000004</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2021-04-22T15:41:29+02:00</CreDtTm>
      </MsgHdr>
      <AcctQryDef>
        <AcctCrit>
          <NewCrit>
            <SchCrit>
              <AcctId>
                <EQ>
                  <Othr>
                    <Id>250788123456</Id>
                  </Othr>
                </EQ>
              </AcctId>
              <AcctOwnr>
                <CtctDtls>
                  <MobNb>250788123456</MobNb>
                </CtctDtls>
              </AcctOwnr>
            </SchCrit>
          </NewCrit>
        </AcctCrit>
      </AcctQryDef>
    </GetAcct>
  </Document>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>i41j0dS1uwC8ggex3M3YYND05g3OipfKT+kiByLo2gY=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>KBBupI04c6OyfqrJVzNtEnyYHsm8i9ZLa7gPFIuvj+gruFls0GWHikzowFTJNqPfPkML7n/sv4dF
1QyAE9RRrvdNMEVoR5WYIsg0J61QgNtx/5Lis30qVEPVo66GOpXoysu6cZ9MnnpiclXzzuk/ZIsH
2tZSvlPqN/rC/W4xOet8UO4dCvoj/tcwr6ukJOh3ArDS2q/AMdzgiyNExaDXx3vGl/wecVgAe/3U
oyG5MWTGOMMFAlk2aGq+Vm/9faePs0st7LvSXT9ySWtz3XHCl1DYmT20bBTw97tJxJeP6+g5q+iE
1FlJxc5rtsyDOxEpA3cfXXsgLNW/3I1Gpp+2dg==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>okTuIE0BJYsd2aX9mw+CyGZt/JwxoaE2RGonnz32biHT8C3rTPNOFz6JPaPxHnZVOvKGxZNAWveM
u6o+BI5NHTAon+7hOHeYp2WoBp+nDwMTjGWkb6K8NUwYw+pBNJnqqyLzUTVvuZDg2VRsflbLhITF
wAKTTnfARBskdKpmY1s6/Unm12cFBiBVHVxPvnR6mwMSZfkU9LY/1Kx11XKyXxPqzzezDwiX6aqr
Wag2ouOFyLaXBvdUxPQkTSOvOJWmdH/E5tItf7+NbTUehaHLYkfCR5YLcAstD6zUfM5YuEKK3DLo
LdhiID9EDBCs6nkpp4GgOkquvgD+l8dGKe3eFQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue></KeyInfo></Signature></BusinessMessage>
```

Tried to run the below in Java 11 -

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-xml-digital-signature-api-overview-and-tutorial.html#GUID-1152D2A5-ECBB-4727-9B0F-1941E4171108

Comment: The 13's are line breaks.  See if this helps : https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/issues/93?force_isolation=true

Comment: Why the line breaks are a problem? Are they causing an issue?

Comment: @aled My partner is not allowing that. So According to https://gist.github.com/shunkica/ab3674e0161c7c1efac1854299813c94 ref I am using java 1.8 which is working fine. But now the digest for the document is generated wrongly.